# Mysql code for incrementing value not working

Tags: mysql, vb.net, increment

This is my Update statement:

```
Update COLOR set Color_Code = 'Color_Code + 1' where id = '"& txt1.text &"'
```

the code above is working, but when I use this in Insert Statement like this:

```
Insert into COLOR(Color_Code) values ('Color_Code + 1')
```

The code above is not working, it insert the value:Color_Code + 1" instead of incrementing it.

Thanks, I am using vb.net here

Comment: In the update you're doing the action depends on a previous data. But the insert function is a new data doesn't depend on any existed data.

Comment: What should it increment when you insert? Apart from that: **use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection**.

Comment: Can you paste the full code, I think you are doing some string concatenation and missing it here

Comment: @7alhashmi: ahh ok sir, How can I increment it if it is a new data? or is it possible or not?, My senior said to me to not use auto increment in that field. tnx

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It should increment the last value in the record, for example the last color_code is 99, when I insert, it should be 100, tnx sir.

Comment: @skv: I'm not doing any string concatenation here sir, and that is the full code for the sql statement, tnx sir.

Comment: your insert does not make sense. You shall at least select max value and increment it to achieve the result you want.

Comment: @LeosLiterak: ahh ok sir tnx for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
INSERT INTO color (color_code)
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(color_code), 0) + 1
  FROM color
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67a5a/1)** demo